# Disabling main pdf with TikZ externalize

Tags: tikz-external

I'm using TikZ externalize to generate multiple figures from a single .tex file. Is there a way to suppress the generation of the large main PDF which contains all those TikZ figures?

Answer (score 4):

You can call pdflatex with the `--draftmode` switch.

```
 pdflatex --shell-escape --draftmode mainfile
```

then no output pdf is produced.